# Laravel5-update table-fill dropdown and display actual value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Being newer to Laravel 5, I am trying to update a table, then i show all fields into a form using blade. I am also able to populate the drop-down list (select) in order to show values from another table, but I can't make the drop-down to point to the value in the main table (the one am trying to update).

> Controller side: I use $user to pass all user data to the view and $profiles to pass data to fill the drop-down

```
public function edit($id){
$user = User::find($id);
$profiles = \DB::table('profiles')->lists('desc_profile', >'id_profile');      
return view('user.edit')->with('user', $user)->with('profiles', $profiles);
    }
```

> View Side:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
        {!!Form::select('profiles', $profiles)!!}
</div>
```

In addition, I can update all the fields in the table BUT the values from the drop-down ... So basically everything is working fine for show and update values except for the ones in the .... drop downs...
need help! THX a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an optional 3rd argument to the `select` method that specifies which option you want to have selected. In other words, you pass in the specific `id_profile` that you want selected.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    {!!Form::select('profiles', $profiles, $user->id)!!}
</div>
```

I passed in the user id as the 3rd argument only because we have no idea how you are structuring your database, but you should adjust that to match what you need.

Comment: Yeah! I ve just got how to do it  minutes ago then i logged into stackoverflow in order to answer myself such a rookie question i did !!!! Then i found your answer..thanks a lot anyway!